# how to access VM services that is reachable from layers-deep jump server only?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding

I have a setup of servers like:

> *Workstation --> Jump1 --> jump2 --> server1:4489*

- so jump1 is only SSH-accessible from Workstation
- jump2 only SSH-accessible from Jump1
- & server1 has a servce running on a non-standard port 4489, and is only reachable from jump2, but not
  SSH-accessible.

**I want to reach server1 service on my workstation like this:
http://localhost:13000**

how to achieve it when one doesn't have an endpoint that is not SSH-accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try SSH port forwarding:

> **NOTE:** I stole [this from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45734070/9270227)

Create/Modify the config file

```bsh
vim ~/.ssh/config
```

```yaml
Host <Host_Name>
    HostName <URL/IP of Jump2>
    User <>
    Port <>
    Identityfile <yyy.pem>
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    ProxyCommand ssh -i <xxx.pem> <user>@<IP/DNS of Jump1> nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
```

Then create a tunnel

```bsh
ssh 13000:<server1>:4489 <Host_Name>
```

now try

```bsh
curl localhost:13000
```

See if that works